# Spinner only displaying one item from JSON

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have a spinner that will display all of supplier's name that will come from JSON. I have retrieved JSON data, stored it in an arraylist and displays it. The problem is that it only displays one item. a recently added item.

here is my code which contains the implementation for the spinner:

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json){
        if(json != null){
            try{
                result = json.getJSONArray("supplier");
                if(!result.toString().equals("[]")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String suppliers = source.getString("SupplierName");
                        //Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "Suppliers: "+suppliers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
                        spinnerArray.add(suppliers);

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

                        spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.fillInStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(json == null) {
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

JSON:

```
{"supplier":[{"SupplierID":"1","SupplierName":"Nike","Address":"161","City":"Caloocan","Region":"NCR","PostalCode":"1114","Phone":"0917123456","Email":"email@mail.com"},{"SupplierID":"2","SupplierName":"Adidas","Address":"36 C","City":"Quezon City","Region":"NCR","PostalCode":"1115","Phone":"7493857","Email":"email@email.com"},{"SupplierID":"3","SupplierName":"NIEK","Address":"","City":"Quezon City","Region":"ARMM","PostalCode":"1104","Phone":"709-2227","Email":"niekniekniek@gmail.com"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set adapter after adding items into the array as follows :

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json){
            if(json != null){
                try{
                    result = json.getJSONArray("supplier");
                    if(!result.toString().equals("[]")) {
                        spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
                            String suppliers = source.getString("SupplierName");
                            //Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "Suppliers: "+suppliers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            spinnerArray.add(suppliers);
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

                            spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.fillInStackTrace();
                }
            } else if(json == null) {
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I did your code. as well as intechanging the declaration and adding of items in the arraylist and it worked. overlooked it in my code. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1. The line where you have initialized the array `spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();`

It should be **outside & before** the `for` loop.

2. The line where you have set the adapter `spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);`

It should be **outside & after** the `for` loop.

**Solution** :

```
spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
                         String suppliers = source.getString("SupplierName");
                          //Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "Suppliers: "+suppliers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          spinnerArray.add(suppliers);


       }
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                            PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
            spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for loop:

set adapter after for loop
create object of array before for loop

```
spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
    String suppliers = source.getString("SupplierName");
   //Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "Suppliers: "+suppliers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    spinnerArray.add(suppliers);
    }
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

      spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove setAdapter code outside alongwith initialization of your ArrayList

```
      @Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json){
    if(json != null){
        try{
            result = json.getJSONArray("supplier");
            if(!result.toString().equals("[]")) {
               spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String suppliers = source.getString("SupplierName");
                    //Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "Suppliers: "+suppliers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    spinnerArray.add(suppliers);

                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

                spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.fillInStackTrace();
        }
    } else if(json == null) {
        Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are initializing the `ArrayList` again and again, check your code and

```
if(!result.toString().equals("[]")) {
         for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject source = result.getJSONObject(i);
              String suppliers = source.getString("SupplierName");
              //Toast.makeText(PurchaseOrder.this, "Suppliers: "+suppliers, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              spinnerArray.add(suppliers);
              ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

              spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
```

move below line

```
spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
```

before this line

```
if(!result.toString().equals("[]"))
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> Declare spinnerArray outside before for loop

`spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();`

make adapter outside after for loop

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                PurchaseOrder.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

                        spinSupplier.setAdapter(adapter);
```